# How can i validate a check box using JustValidate and PHP, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, validation

```
<div class="job-types-container">
  <ul class="cboxtags">
    <?php
      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM job_type";
      $resultJobtype = $mysqli->query($sql2);
      if ($resultJobtype) :
      while ($jobtype = $resultJobtype->fetch_assoc()) :
    ?>

    <li class="cboxtags-list">
      <div class="cboxtags-wrapper" id="jobtypes-validator">
        <input class="cboxtype-input" id="cboxtype-<?= $jobtype['id_name']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="jobtypes[]">
        <label class="cboxtype-label" for="cboxtype-<?= $jobtype['id_name']; ?>">
          <span class="cboxlabel-span">
            <svg class="plus-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
              <!--! Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. -->
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M256 80c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32V224H48c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32H192V432c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32V288H400c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H256V80z" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="check-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M155 396.9L23.3 265.2c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l21.3-21.3c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L160 293l162.8-162.8c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l21.3 21.3c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L187 396.9c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0z"></path>
            </svg>
            <span><?= $jobtype['job_type_name']; ?></span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <?php
        endwhile;
      endif; 
    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here is how i use justvalidate

```
try {
    validatePostForm
      .addField("#jobtitle", [
        {
          rule: "required",
        },
      ])
      .addField("#num-people", [
        {
          rule: "required",
        },
      ])
      .addField("#municipality", [
        {
          rule: "required",
        },
      ])
      .addField("#barangay", [
        {
          rule: "required",
        },
      ])
      .addField("#jobtypes-validator", [
        {
          rule: "required",
        },
      ]);
    console.log("Validation added successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Validation error:", error);
  }
```

Errors:

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

I want to validate the job types using [justvalidate](https://just-validate.dev/) but when I try to use the format in their example it is not working. I also tried to ask in ChatGPT but still not working. Can anyone help me please?

I want that the error will show when there is no selected check box and the error will show in the last element of the list.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `.addRequiredGroup()` as per the [examples](https://just-validate.dev/examples#advanced)? The example has `.addRequiredGroup(
    '#advanced-usage_communication_checkbox_group',
    'You should select at least one communication channel'
  )`. Using `.addField` doesn't make much sense because it's not one field. You said you "used their example" but unless you're looking at a different example, then I don't think you did.

Comment: Thanks for help but i solve the problem now its because it is in conflict with my other JS Script